# How to Run PowerShell JOB in batches of 10 items, after completion advance to next 10 items?

Tags: powershell

Can someone help me with ideas for running PowerShell JOB in batches? 
i.e. for 100 items in the array, run 1st 10 jobs, on completion run next 10, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop that increments by 10 every time:

```
$inputValues = 1..100

for($i = 0; $i -lt $inputValues.Count; $i += 10){
    $batch = $inputValues[$i..($i+9)]
    # start 10 jobs
    $jobs = $batch |ForEach-Object {
        Start-Job {param($value) Do-Something $value} -ArgumentList $_
    }
    # wait for them to finish
    $jobs |Wait-Job |Receive-Job
}
```

Comment: This is a helpful example but on the line that has the for loop you need to add a `.Count` after $inputValues:

`for($i = 0; $i -lt $inputValues; $i += 10){`

becomes:

`for($i = 0; $i -lt $inputValues.Count; $i += 10){`